# HTML Asides - Specifying A Side

Tags: html, css

I've got a couple of asides on a page and can't get them to behave quite how I'd expect. The code in question goes roughly like this:

```
<aside>Table of Contents</aside>
<section>Content</section>
<aside>Related Content</aside>
```

On a thin screen (e.g. my phone), this does exactly what I'd expect. The first aside appears just above the content, the content in the middle, then the last one below. However, on a wider screen, it's not working quite as cleanly. The first aside (ToC) appears to the left of the Content, and the second appears to the right. I would, ideally, like both to appear on the right, while they still appear exactly as they do on mobile. Any help would be great.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `<aside>` or `<section>` - in fact you may as well just use `<span class="something">`. You will need media queries if you want different behaviour on wide/narrow screens.

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking for is called "CSS".  It's a tool for styling your HTML on a display.  There are a variety of CSS tutorials to get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't specify, I am calling desktop size anything greater than `600px`. It's arbitrary. Using `flexbox` ordering, I'm pulling the `section` before both asides, in the first child slot.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order):

> The **order** CSS property sets the order to lay out an item in a flex or
>   grid container. Items in a container are sorted by ascending `order`
>   value and then by their source code order.

This demo is best viewed in *Full page* mode.

```css
aside, section {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
   body {
     display: flex;     
   }
   
   section {
     order: -1;
   }
}
```

```html
<aside>Table of Contents</aside>
<section>Content</section>
<aside>Related Content</aside>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xa8h79gb/)

Comment: Thank you. It was all about order. I still can't see the point in my template's CSS that makes it do other stuff, but just changing the order of each element fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need a grid there, because of that reordering you want on the flow and I'm guessing you want both asides to be one below the other, right?

Something like:

```
@media (screen and min-width: some_width_bigger_than_mobile) {
  #container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr some_width_for_the_asides;
  }

  section {
    grid-columns: 1;
    grid-rows: 1 / span 2;
  }

  aside {
    grid-column: 2;
  }
}
```